# what causes Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'p'

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am having trouble I could not fix this error. I am using this upload script to check the mime type.

> Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'p'
>   Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'g'
>   Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '('

```
if (preg_match('/^image/p?jpeg$/i', $_FILES['upload']['type']) or 

    preg_match('/^image/gif$/i', $_FILES['upload']['type']) or 

    preg_match('/^image/(x-)?png$/i', $_FILES['upload']['type'])) 

{ 

  // Handle the file... 

} 

else 

{ 

  $error = 'Please submit a JPEG, GIF, or PNG image file.'; 

  include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php'; 

  exit(); 

}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: you have to escape **/** in your regex if you use */* as start-end delimiter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything after second `/` (closing [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)) is considered [flags](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). Use another delimiter such as `~`

```
~^image/p?jpeg$~i
```

Or to match the delimiter literal inside the pattern escape it using the backslash:

```
/^image\/p?jpeg$/i
```

Most comfortable to pick a delimiter, that you don't need inside the pattern > no worry for escaping. Frequently used delimiters are `/`,`~`,`#`,`@` or even bracket style delimiters such as `(` pattern `)`.

*side note*

---

You could combine all three `preg_match` to a single one using [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
if(preg_match('~^image/(?:gif|p?jpeg|(?:x-)?png)$~i', $_FILES['upload']['type'])) { ... }
```

`(?:` starts a non-capture [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Good for testing: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xK9nO7/1)

Comment: you mean like this if (preg_match('/\^image/p?jpeg$/i', $_FILES['upload']['type']) or 

    preg_match('/\^image/gif$/i', $_FILES['upload']['type']) or 

    preg_match('/\^image/(x-)?png$/i', $_FILES['upload']['type']))

Comment: @jemz Like this: `preg_match('~^image/p?jpeg$~i'`... or `preg_match('/^image\/p?jpeg$/i'`...